# thread sleep makes main server to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, server, thread-sleep, java-server

I want to write a java multithreaded server. I used this code:

MultiThreadedServer.java :

```
package servers;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable{

    protected int          serverPort   = 8080;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean      isStopped    = false;
    protected Thread       runningThread= null;

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port){
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while(! isStopped()){
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            System.out.println("Request Entered: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            new Thread(
                new WorkerRunnable(
                    clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")
            ).start();
        }
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
    }


    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
        }
    }

}
```

WorkerRunnable.java:

```
package servers;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{
protected Socket clientSocket = null;
protected String serverText   = null;

public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.serverText   = serverText;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " + this.serverText + " - " +time +"").getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        output.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        //report exception somewhere.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I used this code to run main server:

```
    MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(9000);
    new Thread(server).start();
```

then I opened 3 tabs in the web browser and entered http://localhost:9000/ in all of them.
but tabs doesn't run concurrently and responses are received after 2 sec of each other.

I found out that when I run "Thread.sleep" in each WorkerRunnable thread, MultiThreadedServer doesn't accept any request anymore.
Any solution to run all threads concurrently?

Comment: Please show your own code here, not in a link. Let's try to see what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: Post edited, @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: someone help me please.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the error in your code, but if you don't get a decent answer in another day, I can use my rep to place a bounty on your question, something that will bring it lots more attention. But having said that, are you sure that this is the code causing the problem?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for your response.
Yes, I'am sure. This code haven't any error, but requests does not process concurrently, this is my problem.

Comment: When I ran your code above, I didn't have any problems, even with the `Thread.sleep(...)`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you explain how do you test program?
can you send console output?